# How to remove wrapping p tags from acf wysiwyg field string for later custom excerpt processing

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg, advanced-custom-fields

I have a WYSIWG field with the advanced custom fields plugin. When i query it with :

```
<p class="bran-hn news-excerpt"><?php echo custom_field_excerpt('news_post'); ?></p>
```

the output looks like that:

```
<p class="bran-hn news-excerpt"></p>
<p>Worf, It's better than music. It's jazz. Mr. Crusher, ready a collision course with the Borg ship. This is not about revenge. This is about justice. The Federation's gone; the Borg is everywhere! In all trust, [...]</p>
<p></p>
```

But i would have expected and want something like:

```
<p class="bran-hn news-excerpt">Worf, It's better than music. It's jazz. Mr. Crusher, ready a collision course with the Borg ship. This is not about revenge. This is about justice. The Federation's gone; the Borg is everywhere! In all trust, [...]</p>
```

i tried to add

```
$text = strip_tags ($text);
```

right before the strip_shortcodes call into the function querying the wysiwyg custom field:

```
function custom_field_excerpt($title) {
    global $post;
    $text = get_field($title); 
    if ( '' != $text ) {
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
        $excerpt_length = 35; // 20 words
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    return apply_filters('the_excerpt', $text);
}
```

but also no effect. so is there a way to strip the wrapping p tags while keeping possible tags inside the strings text body like e.g. a tags for links. Best regards Ralf

Comment: First off, you need to remove `$text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);` which adds paragraph tags...

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old but maybe it helps someone else.

I had the same issue and using "false, false" as second and third parameter for get_field did the trick.

```
$myField = get_field('field_name', false, false);

echo '<p class="custom-class">'.$myField.'</p>';
```

Comment: This only solves half the issue. It indeed does work and puts the content inside the intended P tag. But it doesn't generate new P tags if there is a paragraph within the content.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the `<p>` from paragraphs? I used this to render the field on a `<button>`, works perfectly.

Comment: @Cthulhu According to the question, the intention was to add a class to a paragraph. Not sure if placing the field content within a <button> tag would have been the same. That has SEO implications too.

Comment: @16am according to the question, the intention was to remove the <p> tags. I tried on a button and it works, my case was different, I just stated that this answer removes the <p> tags perfectly.

Comment: `<section class='whatevers'><?php the_field(); ?></section>` in combination with the given paragraph elements will help. Or, in areas with only one paragraph, 
`<p class='whatevers'><?php get_field('name', false, false); ?></p>`. You can also target the first paragraph with a CSS selector like `:first-of-type`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a simple string replace?

```
$text = get_field('title');
$stripped_text = str_replace(array('<p>','</p>'),'',$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is PHP's strip_tags function. This will remove all tags.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
$stripped_text = strip_tags( get_field( 'field_name' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_filter ('acf_the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use  acf wysiwyg field inside of p tag. Just use  instead of

Answer (score 0):

See the comments in the code for explantions:

```
<?php


// Remove the opening and closing <p> tags
$content = preg_replace('/^<p>(.*?)<\/p>$/', '$1', $content);

// Remove any remaining <p> tags
$content = str_replace('<p>', '', $content);
$content = str_replace('</p>', '', $content);

// Now you can process the modified $content as needed for your custom excerpt

// Example: Get the first 100 characters as the custom excerpt
$excerpt = substr($content, 0, 100);

// Output the custom excerpt
echo $excerpt;
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I see what seems like explanations in code comments. Note that this can be misread as "code-only" answer. I recommend to (keep them there and) add some explanation in prose (i.e. not code-formatted), in order to increase the chances for being perceived as a helpful and clear answer. Have fun.

Comment: Please try to consolidate your answers. I.e. [edit] one to also contain the info from the other and delete the other.